# How can I isolate rows in a 2d numpy matrix that match a specific criteria?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

How can I isolate rows in a 2d numpy matrix that match a specific criteria?  For example if I have some data and I only want to look at the rows where the 0 index has a value of 5 or less how would I retrieve those values?

I tried this approach:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.matrix([
    [10, 8, 2],
    [1, 4, 5],
    [6, 5, 7],
    [2, 2, 10]])

#My attempt to retrieve all rows where index 0 is less than 5
small_data = (data[:, 0] < 5)
```

The output is:

```
matrix([
    [False],
    [ True],
    [False],
    [ True]], dtype=bool)
```

However I'd like the output to be:

```
   [[1, 4, 5],
    [2, 2, 10]]
```

Another approach may be for me to loop through the matrix rows and if the 0 index is smaller than 5 append the row to a list but I am hoping there is a better way than that.

Note: I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: `data[(data[:, 0] < 5):, 0]`

Comment: @Coldspeed That seems wrong, did you mean `data[(data[:, 0] < 5), :]`?

Comment: @MSeifert Yep, something around that. If I was near a machine I'd have checked before posting. My numpy skills are still developing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: [Don't use `np.matrix`, use normal `np.array`s](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use).

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[10, 8, 2],
                 [1, 4, 5],
                 [6, 5, 7],
                 [2, 2, 10]])
```

Then you can always use [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) (based on the boolean array you get when you do comparisons) to get the desired rows:

```
>>> data[data[:, 0] < 5]
array([[ 1,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  2, 10]])
```

or [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays):

```
>>> data[np.where(data[:, 0] < 5)]
array([[ 1,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  2, 10]])
```

Answer (score 1):

That way you got a logical array that you can use to select the desired rows.

```
>>> data = np.matrix([
[10, 8, 2],
[1, 4, 5],
[6, 5, 7],
[2, 2, 10]])
>>> data = np.array(data)
>>> data[(data[:, 0] < 5), :]
array([[ 1,  4,  5],
   [ 2,  2, 10]])
```

You can also use `np.squeeze` to filter the rows.

```
>>> ind = np.squeeze(np.asarray(data [:,0]))<5
>>> data[ind,:]
array([[ 1,  4,  5],
   [ 2,  2, 10]])
```

Comment: I am getting an error "Too many indices for array" for the top half of your answer.  The np.squeeze part works great though!

Comment: @CSLearner I added the initialization of `data` to make sure that we are running the same thing. Weird cause it works fine for me. Can you please try to re-run the full first part of the answer?

Comment: Oh you are correct, I tested it and it works.  Although the parenthesis turned out to be unnecessary so I could also do this:

data[data[:, 0] < 5, :]

Answer (score -2):

use the following code.

`data[data[small_data,:]]`

That would work

Comment: Or equivalently, `data[data[data[:,0]<5], :]`. Which just looks hilariously wrong.

Comment: I just tried this and got an error: "IndexError: too many indices for array".  

My code was:
output = data[data[small_data, :]]

Am I missing something?